# PFree is 0 on a drive that shouldn't be full

Tags: 12.04

I run a ubuntu 12.04 Server mainly for Owncloud and haven't been able to `use apt-get upgrade`. When I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` it said there might be a problem with space in my filesystem. `df` showed that `/boot` was 100% full, so after some googling I removed a couple old kernel files. Still the problem remains.

Using `sudo pvs` gave me:

```
owncloud@Cloudserver:~$ sudo pvs
PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
/dev/dm-3  Cloudserver lvm2 a-   1,82t    0
```

while at the same time no other filesystem seems to be full:

```
owncloud@Cloudserver:~$ df
Dateisystem                   1K-Blöcke  Benutzt  Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/mapper/Cloudserver-root 1918235728 54167116 1766627844    3% /
udev                            1913652        4    1913648    1% /dev
tmpfs                            782532      276     782256    1% /run
none                               5120        0       5120    0% /run/lock
none                            1956324        0    1956324    0% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/pdc_fabfeiicc1       233191   102342     118408   47% /boot
```

Now I am wondering how can I find out what is taking up all this space and how to get it running again?

Comment: I think `PFree=0` just tells you that you've allocated all the available Physical Extents (PEs) of the volume group to one or more logical volumes: it doesn't tell you anything about the filesystem usage *within* those LVs. A more useful diagnostic would be to check the inode usage e.g. `df -i` or `df -hi`.